# Resizing an SVG to fill a div

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a div with an SVG inside of it[image: my map]

The div is outlines by the blue dots and the SVG by the green. My SVG code inside of my HTML file:

```
<svg class="svg" height="500px" width="50%">
  <g class="chart" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g class="state-g"> (Map here) </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My relevant CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  align-content: center;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.svg {
  outline: 5px dotted blue;
  font: inherit;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

svg g.chart {
  outline: 5px dotted green;
```

Comment: Your SVG has explicit hard-coded dimensions `height="500px" width="50%"`, and nothing else in the CSS it attempting to make it fill its parent (width:100%, height:100%, etc)

Comment: @Jeremy-Thille Removing height="500px" width="50%" only makes the blue box smaller. The green box doesn't change size or fill the box.

Comment: You need a viewBox attribute instead of the  width and height attributes.  This way the svg will take all the width available inside the div.

Comment: But you removed the hardcoded constraints. Now take over with the CSS and set your SVG's dimensions.

Comment: Removing the height and width constraints and then adding   height: 100%;
  width: 100%; to the CSS changes nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you want your SVG to automatically scale to fill its container then it needs to have a `viewBox` attribute.

```
<svg class="svg" viewBox="...something...">
  <g class="chart" transform="translate(0,0)">
    <g class="state-g"> (Map here) </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The correct values for that `viewBox` will depend on the bounds of the *content* of that SVG.  Check your original map file:

- If it had a `viewBox`, then use that.
- If it didn't have a `viewBox`, but it had hardwired `width` and `height`, then use those.  For instance, if it had `width="200px" height="350px"`, then replace those values with `viewBox="0 0 200 350"`.
- If it had neither. Then you will need to work out the correct viewBox values.  There are several ways to do that.  Check other questions on StackOverflow for some solutions.  Or post a link to your SVG and we can tell you what it should be.